# Thoughts on streamlining multiple .Net apps

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, architecture, content-management-system

We have a series of ASP.Net applications that have been written over the course of 8 years.  Mostly in the first 3-4 years.  They have been running quite well with little maintenance, but  new functionality is being requested and we are running into IDE and platform issues.  The apps were written in .Net 1.x and 2.x and run in separate spaces but are presented as a single suite of applications which use a common navigation toolbar (implemented as a user control).  Every time we want to add something to a menu in the nav we have to modify it in all the apps which is a pain.  Also, the various versions of Crystal reports and that we used tables to organize the visual elements and we end up with a mess, especially with all the multi-platform .Net versions running.  We need to streamline the suite of apps and make it easier to add on new apps without a hassle.  We also need to bring all these apps under one .Net platform and IDE.

In addition, there is a WordPress blog styled to match the style of the application suite "integrated" into the UI and a link to a MediaWiki Wiki application as well.

My current thinking is to use an open source content management system (CMS) like Joomla (PHP based unfortunately, but it works well) as the user interface framework for style templating and menu management.  Joomla's article management would allow us to migrate the Wiki content into articles which could be published without interfering with the .Net apps.  Then essentially use an IFrame within an "article" to "host" the .Net application, then...

Upgrade the .Net apps to VS2010, strip out all the common header/footer controls and migrate the styles to use the style sheets used in the CMS.

As I write this, I certainly realize this is a lot of work and there are optimization issues which this may cause as well as using IFrames seems a bit like cheating and I've read about issues with IFrames.

I know that we could use .Net application styling, but it seems like a lot more work (not sure really).  Also, the use of a CMS to handle the blog and wiki also seems appealing, unless there is a .Net CMS out there that can handle all of these requirements.

Given this information, I am looking to know if I am totally going in the wrong direction? We tried to use open source and integrate it over time, but not this has become hard to maintain. Am I not aware of some technology out there that will meet our requirements?  Did we do this right and should we just focus on getting the .Net streamlined?  I understand that no matter what we do, it's going to be a lot of work.  The communities considerable experience would be helpful.  Thanks!!

PS - A complete rewrite is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, we're in the midst of a project to do something that sounds familiar. We're using  [www.sitecore.net CMS](http://www.sitecore.net) but you could use the Open Source alternative [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) again both of these will have a learning curve, but they're .Net apps and aren't targetted specifically at blogs. SiteCore ultimately can use normal .Net user controls if you want, though it's slightly against their model, but it works.

One thing I'll warn you of is SiteCore Must be the root of your website, it has to control the root of the domain (it has a urlrewriting module that needs to be at the root) and you can tell it to exclude certain folders where your applications might live. You can obviously put your navigation in a folder under the root of the site. Also note SiteCore's a .Net 3.5 application running under the 2.0 runtime.

Are your sub-applications.. Actual seperate applications in virtual dirs or something I'm guessing?

Comment: I'm using Umbraco, ASP.NET MVC and user controls for my current project.  The main site is ASP.NET MVC and I'm using a 404 handler to call out to the content.  The biggest problem I'm butting up against is effectively and efficiently using revision control with Umbraco.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the .Net apps, you may find [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) to be a useful choice.

It's a CMS where you write widgets ('modules') in .Net, then add them to the pages of the CMS. In your case, you'd wrap your existing functionality in such widgets. I've done exactly this several times, and now that I'm used to it it's no big deal.

The downside is you have to learn to swim in the DNN environment, which (like any CMS) has a bit of a learning curve.

I'd have to know a lot more about your existing apps to be sure this is a plausible option. If it looks appealing, you should probably contact someone who's dealt with a situation like yours (such as myself) and go into detail. It's *very* easy to find yourself in a dead end with these CMS frameworks.

**Edit**: Like a product mentioned in a different answer, DNN has to control the top level of its subdomain -- all requests begin by going through Default.aspx and are then dispatched in various ways.